# What is the damage of Echo Wave "Dragon"?

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

In Iceborne, the Hunting Horn received several new melodies that can be played by combining the new echo note with any other note, except for white and purple. When combined with the orange note, the melody produced is Echo Wave "Dragon", which creates a shockwave that deals dragon elemental damage.

What is the motion value of this attack? Is it pure dragon damage, and does it scale with the weapon's attack like elemental ammo? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo Wave "Dragon" is a strange type of attack which does a dragon attack, but **ignores** the weapon element.

The physical MV is "25+20×(Echo Wave "Dragon" stacks)", while the elemental damage seems to be calculated by "(600×(Echo Wave "Dragon" stacks)+(Additive dragon elemental effects))×(Multiplicative dragon elemental effects)÷10×(True raw)" and directly decremented by the monster armor.

On top of that, all the Echo Wave attacks don't crit, and ignore the weapon's current sharpness and instead uses the green sharpness (Raw×1.05+Ele×1.0) multiplication.

Source: http://inven.co.kr/board/powerbbs.php?come_idx=3749&l=7383